# ecs-cli up does not create ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to launch an ECS cluster using the cli, but get stuck on EC2 instances not being created.

I've configured my ecs credentials, adding all the missing permissions extracted from the CloudFormation errors - at least I don't see any additional errors now. I've configured a simple cluster configuration.

~/.ecs/config

```
clusters:
  mycluster:
    cluster: mycluster
    region: eu-north-1
    default_launch_type: EC2
```

And this is the cli command I run;

```sh
ecs-cli up --keypair myKeyPair --capability-iam \
--size 1 --instance-type t2.micro \
--cluster-config mycluster --cluster mycluster \
--launch-type EC2 --force --verbose
```

I get no error messages, the cluster is created, but I see no instances connected to it, and especially no instances on EC2.

This is the output from the cli command;

```sh
INFO[0000] Using recommended Amazon Linux 2 AMI with ECS Agent 1.29.1 and Docker version 18.06.1-ce 
INFO[0000] Created cluster               cluster=mycluster region=eu-north-1
INFO[0000] Waiting for your CloudFormation stack resources to be deleted... 
INFO[0000] Cloudformation stack status   stackStatus=DELETE_IN_PROGRESS
DEBU[0030] Cloudformation stack status   stackStatus=DELETE_IN_PROGRESS
DEBU[0061] Cloudformation create stack call succeeded    stackId=0xc00043ab11
INFO[0061] Waiting for your cluster resources to be created... 
DEBU[0061] parsing event                 eventStatus=CREATE_IN_PROGRESS resource="arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-north-1:999987631111:stack/amazon-ecs-cli-setup-mycluster/11111111-aba2-11e9-ac3c-0e40cf291592"
INFO[0061] Cloudformation stack status   stackStatus=CREATE_IN_PROGRESS
DEBU[0091] parsing event                 eventStatus=CREATE_IN_PROGRESS resource=subnet-0cc4a3aa110555d42
DEBU[0091] Cloudformation stack status   stackStatus=CREATE_IN_PROGRESS
DEBU[0121] parsing event                 eventStatus=CREATE_IN_PROGRESS resource=rtbassoc-05c185a5aa11ca22e
INFO[0121] Cloudformation stack status   stackStatus=CREATE_IN_PROGRESS
DEBU[0151] parsing event                 eventStatus=CREATE_COMPLETE resource=rtbassoc-05c185a5aa11ca22e
DEBU[0151] Cloudformation stack status   stackStatus=CREATE_IN_PROGRESS
DEBU[0181] parsing event                 eventStatus=CREATE_COMPLETE resource=rtbassoc-05c185a5aa11ca22e
INFO[0181] Cloudformation stack status   stackStatus=CREATE_IN_PROGRESS
DEBU[0212] parsing event                 eventStatus=CREATE_COMPLETE resource=amazon-ecs-cli-setup-mycluster-EcsInstanceProfile-1KS4Q3W9HAAAA
DEBU[0212] Cloudformation stack status   stackStatus=CREATE_IN_PROGRESS
DEBU[0242] parsing event                 eventStatus=CREATE_COMPLETE resource="arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-north-1:999987631111:stack/amazon-ecs-cli-setup-mycluster/11111111-aba2-11e9-ac3c-0e40cf291592"
VPC created: vpc-033f7a6fedfee256d
Security Group created: sg-0e4461f781bad6681
Subnet created: subnet-0cc4a3aa110555d42
Subnet created: subnet-0a4797072dc9641d2
Cluster creation succeeded.
```

Running describe-clusters after a couple of hours;

```sh
aws ecs describe-clusters --clusters mycluster --region eu-north-1
```

gives the following output;

```sh
{
    "clusters": [
        {
            "status": "ACTIVE", 
            "statistics": [], 
            "tags": [], 
            "clusterName": "mycluster", 
            "registeredContainerInstancesCount": 0, 
            "pendingTasksCount": 0, 
            "runningTasksCount": 0, 
            "activeServicesCount": 0, 
            "clusterArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-north-1:999987631111:cluster/mycluster"
        }
    ], 
    "failures": []
}
```

Does anyone know what I might be missing? I've not hit any limits, since I've only got 1 other running instance (on a different region).

Comment: can verify from the console that EC2 is existed but in the cluster list?

Comment: Hi! No EC2 instances are present in the console. So they haven't even been created.

Comment: Might it be launching in a different region, since no region was specified in the `esc-cli` command?

Comment: Thanks, I actually went through all the regions, but no, no instance was created. It should pick the default aws region if none is specified (which I've specified as eu-north-1). I just tried again by specifying --region eu-north-1 , same results. I wonder if it could be some access rights thing? Even though no errors are shown? The user has full ec2 and ecs access rights, among other things.

Comment: FOUND IT!!! t2.micro wasn't available in eu-north-1. I tried with t3.micro and it worked. They should really give you some kind of warning or error message.

Comment: Did you figure out what was happening? Same thing here, can’t find a way to resolve that

Comment: Sorry for late response, yes, I created a t3.micro instance instead, since the t2.micro wasn't available in the eu-north-1 region.